# How to get data in PHP array with foreach?

Tags: php

I have data like this and I need to get it to variable for use please suggest to me how to get them to variable

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
                    [category] => yyyyyyyy
                    [id] => 12345666666
                    [data] => ABCDE
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                     [name] => ZZZZZZZZZZZ
                    [category] => JJJJJJ
                    [id] => 88888888888888
                    [data] => ABCDEHIJK
                )

        )

)
```

Thank you vary much.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array['data'] as $data) {
    echo $data['name'];
    echo $data['category'];
    ...
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php